# Image preloader does not wait long enough

Tags: javascript, preloader

This preloader should loop through each of the sources and populate the array of images adding an onload event to the image. The source is added and when the image is loaded it increases the count. Once the count reaches the number of images in the list all images should have loaded.

BUT its not working, any help please

```
images = [
    'images/pizza-slice-green.png',
    'images/pizza-slice-orange.png',
    'images/pizza-slice-pink.png',
    'images/pizza-slice-purple.png',
    'images/pizza-slice-red.png',
]

var count = 0;
var image_array = [];
for (var i = 0; i<images.length; i++){
    image_array.push(new Image());
    image_array[i].onload = function(){
        count += 1;
        console.log(count);
        if (count === images.length){
            $('#preloader').hide();
        }
    };
    image_array[i].src = images[i];
}
```

Comment: This code seems to work fine. So what's the problem?

Comment: Note that as you retry the code, the browser will have cached the image, thus it completes immediately.

Comment: Must be something to do with FullPage.js that I am not aware of, *Scratching head*

Comment: So, what's the issue? The images don't come into view? Or do you need a delay?

Comment: We have gone about it in a diffrent way, which is unrelated yet successful.